# Scan image vulnerability- CVE-2022-40674 for expat package

Tags: security, dockerfile, debian, expat-parser, debian-packaging

We are trying to build container image for GCP cloud run service from base image of python:3.9-slim and we could see that there is a recent vulnerability for the expat package(CVE-2022-40674) which is stopping the whole CI/CD process.

we tried to upgrade the package using (RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y) as well but its pointing to the version 2.2.10 which still contains the vulnerability. I am assuming that the latest version 2.4.8-2 is in un-stable version so its not upgrading to it; is there any interim solution to solve this issue?

Error:
CRITICAL            9.8         projects/goog-vulnz/notes/CVE-2022-40674    expat             2.2.10

Related urls:
https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/source-package/expat
https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/expat

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9-slim
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y

# Allow statements and log messages to immediately appear in the Knative logs
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED True

ARG APP_ENV
ENV APP_ENV=${APP_ENV}
RUN echo $APP_ENV

ENV APP_HOME /app
ENV PYTHONPATH /app
ENV CLOUD True
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY . ./
```